# how to split numpy array by step?

Tags: numpy

how to split numpy array by step?

Example:

I have array:

`[3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 3, 1]`

I want to spit like this:

```
[3, 5, 6, 3]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Or a more understandable example:

```
['a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'b2'] -- > ['a1', 'b1'] and ['a2', 'b2']
```

Comment: `arr1, arr2 = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr, (2,4), (8,16))`, IIUC. Surprisingly, there is an unexpected `6` in the desired output after the split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with array slicing.

```
arr = np.array([3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 3, 1])

A = arr[::2]
B = arr[1::2]
```

see [docs on slices here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice)